# How can I search by the ingredientId inside the array in the following model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to peform a search based on the ingredientIds on the items array

I'm trying to make a search that will return all the recipes that contain the ingredientId inside ingredients.items, I already tried

```
Recipe.find({
    "ingredients.items.ingredientId": ingredientId,
  });
```

but it is returning an empty array, this is the model

```
const recipeSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  portions: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ingredients: {
    items: [
      {
        ingredientId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Ingredients",
          required: false,
        },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: false },
      },
    ],
  },
  instructions: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I would suggest trying this, your code looks right to me.

```
import { Types} from 'mongoose'

Recipe.find({
    "ingredients.items.ingredientId": new Types.ObjectId(ingredientId),
});
```